# Traefik and Minecraft

Tags: docker, server, docker-compose, minecraft, traefik

i'm trying to set up a Minecraft server in a VPS managed with traefik.
After I start the docker container and I tried to reach the server via weburl it fails for timeout.
If I use the server IP address is's working.
I think that the problem is that if I try to reach the default server port in Minecraft (25565) via domain the port is not redirected correctly to the container.
Also, I got to mention that my domain is under Cloudflare, but I don't think that is the problem because I've tried to bypass it turning on the development mode whit no positive results.
I've added a custom entry point as so

```
 defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http","mc"]
 [entryPoints.mc]
   address = ":25565"
```

then in the labels of my docker-compose I've used these settings:

```
# map host port
ports:
    - 25565:25565 

networks:
  - traefik_proxy 
  - default
labels:
     - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:mc.myserver.net"
     - "traefik.basic.port=25565"
     - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=mc"
```

But it still fails.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research the problem should be that at the moment traefik doesn't handle all the tcp traffic but only the http related one (https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/10). From what i understand it will be supported in the V2 
I've managed to make it work just altering the cloudflare setting adding a SRV records
as follow 
Name - _minecraft
Value - SRV 1 1 25565